# Background SVG image inline not displayed

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I've been trying to insert a simple SVG image as inline background, but  for some unknown reason it's failing in IE and Firefox.

If I encode the data as base64 it works, but it's much uglier, the syntax should be OK because other inline image with a circle instead of a path works correctly. The SVG data has been optimized with https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ I haven't modified it manually.

```css
div {
   height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:100% 0;
  }
.utf {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M1.168.47L15.53.53l.033 14.332z' fill='#00c000' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke='#00c000' /></svg>");

}
.base64 {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxNicgaGVpZ2h0PScxNicgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDE2IDE2Jz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMS4xNjguNDdMMTUuNTMuNTNsLjAzMyAxNC4zMzJ6JyBmaWxsPScjMDBjMDAwJyBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9J2V2ZW5vZGQnIHN0cm9rZT0nIzAwYzAwMCcvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
}
.circle {
  background-image:
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' /></svg>");
```

```html
<div class='utf'>UTF</div>
<div class='base64'>Base64</div>
<div class='circle'>utf circle</div>
```

Run this example, there are three divs, the first one fails, the second one that has the SVG data as base64 works, and the last one that has the data as plain text but with a circle element works.

Why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # character in a URL is a reserved character for the start of a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) so your URL is invalid.

You must encode each # as %23.

Your final example happens not to contain a # which is why it works.